# PHP Yii way to create a link to an element ID

Tags: php, html, yii

I've looked around and can't seem to find a way to create an anchor tag linking to an id.

For example,

```
<a href='#element-id'> Link to an element </a>
```

As an attempt to have the page scroll to the specified element.  For whatever reason, the link is being added to the URL, but isn't moving the page.  I've tested with both the CHTML::Link method, and just a standard html  tag.  Is this a Yii thing in how it handles URLs?

Comment: it has nothing to do with yii, paste your CHtml::link s code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
CHtml::link( 'Link to an element', array('controller/action','#'=>'element-id'));
```

Comment: This is what I had before, but wasn't working.  However, when typing it out a second time, I accidentally included the '#' in the element-id, and now it's fine.  The url being generated is:

    index.php/site/index/##element-id

Is the second '#' expected behaviour?